# Is it possible to have a hosts override with headless Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Is it possible to tell headless Chrome somehow to resolve example.com to 127.0.0.1 without editing /etc/hosts ? I am testing an oauth login flow where the provider determines the hostname where it redirects to based on the application ID and this makes automated testing problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the command line argument `--host-rules="MAP my.site.com 127.0.0.1"`, like this: `chrome --host-rules="MAP my.site.com 127.0.0.1"` will do a host override, currently headless chrome doesn't support this https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=798793 .

Note if you are using a self signed certificate, make sure it has a subject alternative name of `IP.1` `127.0.0.1` , not `my.site.com`.